# will the Apache-Pulsar Java client work on RaspberryPi4 (ARMv8)?

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4, apache-pulsar

I would like to stream some data from a RPi4 with ARMv8 architecture using the [Java client for Apache-Pulsar](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/client-libraries-java/). I tried initially to do so with the Python client but, unfortunately, being that just a wrapper around the C++ library, it is not compatible with ARMv8 architectures.

So I am wondering if the Java client will work.

Comment: If it's pure Java (i.e. does not contain native libraries) then it should work.

Comment: Apache-Pulsar it's a Java project, if that's what you meant!

Comment: If the Apache Pulsar client consists of just Java code, then it will work on any platform for which there is a suitable JVM available, including Raspberry Pi, so most likely it will work. In rare cases however, Java projects make use of native libraries = libraries written in for example C or C++ that only work on a specific platform. That doesn't seem to be the case however (at least I don't see anything in the docs about it) for the Apache Pulsar client. In other words, just try it, it will most likely work.

Comment: Java with official native Pulsar client/library works on RPI4 as well as on NVIDIA Jetson and NVIDIA XAVIER NX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran some talks on RPI4 and NVIDIA Jetson sending data to Pulsar via various mechanisms.

GoLang -> Native Pulsar,   Python -> MQTT, Java -> Pulsar

- https://github.com/tspannhw/SpeakerProfile/tree/main/2021/talks
- https://github.com/tspannhw/FLiP-IoT
- https://github.com/tspannhw/FLiP-EdgeAI
- https://github.com/tspannhw/FLiP-Jetson

To get access to all the Pulsar people in one location, sign up for the summit.

https://streamnative.io/en/blog/community/2021-09-07-speakers-announced-for-pulsar-virtual-summit-europe-2021/

Comment: brilliant! Thanks Tim!! One off-topic question: why you refer to Native Pulsar when talking about GoLang but simply "Pulsar" with Java?

Comment: Ok this was my bad writing, let me be more clear.
For my Python code I used the paho-mqtt library to send messages to MQTT (This is Pulsar running MoP).
For my Golang code, I used the official Pulsar Go library
For my Java code, I used the official Pulsar Java library.   I did not use C++, Python or NodeJS official libraries because of lack of support on RPI or NVIDIA Jetson architectures/CPU.
I should have called both native pulsar or called them official libraries.

Comment: I have compiled the native C++ and Python libraries for Raspberry Pi4. https://github.com/tspannhw/PulsarOnRaspberryPi